# "Docker Compose Up" in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am following this guide to get docker-compose containers up and running on azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose

I am at the last part where I "docker compose up". However, I am getting an error shown below

[image]

I am looking for solutions to this that I can understand and execute. Here is what I found online suggesting to increase the timeout length. I do not know how to do this:

https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/7865

Could someone elaborate and guide me to solve this? Please and thank you!

Comment: Did you run before `docker-compose push`? I followed tutorial without the issue.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej yes, I am able to follow the example and get it up and running. However, with my own, it loads too long and times-out. I believe it just needs more time as stated in the solution here: https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/7865

Question is, how do I incorporate an image builder into the setup for it to work?